How do I use the changed cell as a variable in a Worksheet change event macro?
I have a sheet where I want a macro to run whenever a cell is changed within a specified range. I have set this up and got it to work. What doesn't work is the code that I want to run upon this cell change.
I have columns with numbers. The first column is the latest price. The next columns are a history of previous prices paid. I want the macro to do the following: Upon entering a new number into the latest Number column, delete the last price in the row (Column F), then cut the range from A2:E2, Select B2 and paste. Finally select range A2 again. This code will need to work if any cell changes in a certain range, which is set with the KeyCells variable. I basically want it to look at the cell where the change happened, and perform the code in that row.
See the example picture for a layout. Example Layout
Here is my code. I'm sure this is amateur. I am a newbie at this and trying to work my way through. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim KeyCells As Range
  Dim Current As Range
  Dim DeleteCell As Range
  Dim CopyRange As Range
    
  Set KeyCells = Range("A2:A15")
  Set Current = Target
  Set DeleteCell = Target.Offset(0, 5)
  Set CopyRange = Range(Target, Target.Offset(0, 5))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

    DeleteCell.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    CopyRange.Cut
    Current.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Current.Select
   
End If

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub

I have tried various different ways to do this and have not been successfull. My thinking is that I somehow need to capture the cell where the change happened I a variable to use throughout the code, but it seems almost like this is a moving target as my code runs, and it just keeps repeating.

You need to disable event handling with application.enableevents = false otherwise your worksheet change will trigger a worksheet change entering you into an infinite loop.

That worked great!! Thank you very much!

btw, Range(Target.Address) is equalient to Target. Range(Target, Target.Offset(0, 5)) can be replaced with Target.Resize(1, 6).

A Worksheet Change: Backup Changed Value If Number

Basically, there are numbers in column A. If a number is changed, the left 4 columns are copied to the last 4 columns while the new number is copied to the first column of the backup columns B:F.
For example, if the value in A2 is changed, it will check if the new value is a number. If so, it will check if the number is not equal to the value in B2. If so, it will copy A2:E2 to B2:F2 i.e. shifting the values from B2:E2 to C2:F2, adding the new value to B2 while losing the previous (last) value in F2.
It will do this for any reasonable number (hundreds) of changed cells (at a time) in A2:A1048576.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TOP_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    Const BACKUP_COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 1
    Const BACKUP_CELLS_COUNT As Long = 5
    
    ' Dynamically, using only the address of the top cell, create a reference
    ' to the single-column range being monitored for a change.
    Dim mrg As Range:
    With Me.Range(TOP_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Set mrg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) ' A2:A1048576 (A2:A65536)
    End With
    
    ' Create a reference to the 'key cells' i.e. the cells that have changed,
    ' AND intersect with (are part of) the monitored range.
    ' For example, you might have copied values to the range 'A1:E2'
    ' which is then the range represented by the 'Target' variable.
    ' Then you would want only 'A2' included in the range.
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(mrg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no 'key cells'
    
    ' Prevent re-triggering this event while writing to the sheet.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Note that this disables all events so it is crucial
    ' to re-enable them before exiting the code.
    ' Hence the error-handling routine.
    
    ' In the corresponding If statement below ('If IsOffsetOne Then'),
    ' see how the code is different (more complicated) when
    ' the backup column offset is not 1 i.e. the backup cells are not adjacent.
    Dim IsOffsetOne As Boolean: IsOffsetOne = (BACKUP_COLUMN_OFFSET = 1)
    ' The parentheses above are redundant but IMO they increase readability.
    
    Dim icell
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        If VarType(icell.Value) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            With icell
                ' If the changed value is different than the backup value...
                If .Value <> .Offset(, BACKUP_COLUMN_OFFSET).Value Then
                    If IsOffsetOne Then ' simple (backup is adjacent)
                        With .Resize(, BACKUP_CELLS_COUNT)
                            .Offset(, BACKUP_COLUMN_OFFSET).Value = .Value
                        End With
                    Else ' not so simple (backup is not adjacent)
                        With .Offset(, BACKUP_COLUMN_OFFSET)
                            With .Resize(, BACKUP_CELLS_COUNT - 1)
                                .Offset(, 1).Value = .Value ' shift old
                            End With
                            .Value = icell.Value ' add new
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next icell
    
ProcExit:
    ' No code here!
    ' After the following line, all errors are ignored until the next
    ' 'On Error' statement. This is done to prevent an endless loop
    ' when an error would occur in the continuation of the code.
    ' Then the code would repeatedly redirect to the 'ClearError' label below.
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping
        ' Any other code!
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        ' Any other code!
    On Error GoTo 0 ' disable error trapping
    ' No code here!
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit ' end error-handling routine; redirect to 'ProcExit' label
End Sub

